# Aligning the cell contents to the middle of the cell while using multicolumn

Tags: align, multicolumn

While using this table environment, I need to get the cell contents of the second row to be in the middle of each cell. But, I am getting all of them aligned to top of the cells (although there are centered vertically). Can anybody guide me what mistake I am doing?

[image: table]

```
 \documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{report}
 \usepackage[linktocpage,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black]{hyperref}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{multicol}
 \usepackage{array,booktabs}
 \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
 \newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
 \usepackage{longtable}
 %\usepackage[dvips]{color}  % comment it to run with png images and pdflatex
 %\usepackage{epsfig} %Sharma commented
 \usepackage{graphicx} % Sharma introduced

 %\usepackage{mciteplus}
 \usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
 \usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}
 \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

 \usepackage{enumerate}
 \usepackage{bm}
 \usepackage{braket}
 \usepackage{microtype}
 \usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
 \usepackage{color}
 \usepackage{fixltx2e}
 \usepackage[top=1.0in, bottom=1.0in, left=1.0in, right=1.0in]{geometry}

 \setlength{\textheight}{23cm}
 \setlength{\textwidth}{15cm}

 \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.4in}
 \setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{table}
 \centering
 \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
 \begin{tabular}{|*{16}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.8cm}|}} \hline

 \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{ GQD} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{ BN-zigzag-ed-GQD} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{
 BN-partial-ed-GQD}  \\ \hline

 \multicolumn{2}{|M{1.6cm}|}{Avg. edge} & \multicolumn{2}{C{1.6cm}|}{Avg. 2$^{nd}$ zigzag line} &
 \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ B-border}   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ N-border}  &
 \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ B-edge}     & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ N-edge} &
 \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ B-border}   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ N-border}  \\  \hline

 spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$ & spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$ & spin-${\alpha}$ &
 spin-${\beta}$ &
 spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$ & spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$ & spin-${\alpha}$ &
 spin-${\beta}$ &
 spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$ & spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$ \\ \hline

 19.02 & 19.02 & 21.48 & 21.49 & 20.81 & 20.81 & 22.26 & 22.26 & 11.99 & 10.82 & 10.85 & 12.01 &
 7.21 & 7.81 & 8.38 & 7.81  \\  \hline

 \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{ Charge transfer} & - 0.67 & - 0.67 & + 0.78 & + 0.78 & + 0.58 & - 0.59 & -
 0.56 &
 + 0.6 & - 0.61 & + 0.01 & + 0.57 & - 0.002 \\ \hline

 \end{tabular}
 }
 \end{table}

 \end{document}
```

Kindly, help me.
p.s.: there are some unnecessary packages (for this table), but, they are required for my thesis. So, I kept them as it is (if by chance, they can create any problem, please do let me know).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: `spin-α spin-β spin-α spin-β ...` isn't this repeated information? α and β were enough and spin can be a heading.

Comment: Thanks for the comment henrique. I have edited the question to exactly reproduce the problem. Just copy the code and type pdflatex *.tex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change `p` in the definition of `C` to `m`.

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
```

Full code:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{report}
 \usepackage[linktocpage,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black]{hyperref}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{multicol}
 \usepackage{array,booktabs}
 \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
 \usepackage{longtable}
 %\usepackage[dvips]{color}  % comment it to run with png images and pdflatex
 %\usepackage{epsfig} %Sharma commented
 \usepackage{graphicx} % Sharma introduced

 %\usepackage{mciteplus}
 \usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
 \usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}
 \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

 \usepackage{enumerate}
 \usepackage{bm}
 \usepackage{braket}
 \usepackage{microtype}
 \usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
 \usepackage{color}
 \usepackage{fixltx2e}
 \usepackage[top=1.0in, bottom=1.0in, left=1.0in, right=1.0in]{geometry}

 \setlength{\textheight}{23cm}
 \setlength{\textwidth}{15cm}

 \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.4in}
 \setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{table}
 \centering
 \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
 \begin{tabular}{|*{16}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.8cm}|}} \hline

 \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{ GQD} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{ BN-zigzag-ed-GQD} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{
 BN-partial-ed-GQD}  \\ \hline

 \multicolumn{2}{|C{1.6cm}|}{Avg. edge} & \multicolumn{2}{C{1.6cm}|}{Avg. 2$^{nd}$ zigzag line} &
 \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ B-border}   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ N-border}  &
 \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ B-edge}     & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ N-edge} &
 \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ B-border}   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ N-border}  \\  \hline

 spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$ & spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$ & spin-${\alpha}$ &
 spin-${\beta}$ &
 spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$ & spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$ & spin-${\alpha}$ &
 spin-${\beta}$ &
 spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$ & spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$ \\ \hline

 19.02 & 19.02 & 21.48 & 21.49 & 20.81 & 20.81 & 22.26 & 22.26 & 11.99 & 10.82 & 10.85 & 12.01 &
 7.21 & 7.81 & 8.38 & 7.81  \\  \hline

 \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{ Charge transfer} & - 0.67 & - 0.67 & + 0.78 & + 0.78 & + 0.58 & - 0.59 & -
 0.56 &
 + 0.6 & - 0.61 & + 0.01 & + 0.57 & - 0.002 \\ \hline

 \end{tabular}
 }
 \end{table}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Its not working using the above manner.  Can you suggest something else.

Comment: Dear krnk, it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. If possible, could you please explain, why the same code didn't work, when I have used newcolumtype as 'M', but working with 'C'. I couldn't see any difference except the letters. Please let me know any obvious mistake which I am doing. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 3):

The best is to use `tabularx` here, I think. Also, one can play with the values of `\tabcolsep`and the size of the font. With `\scriptsize`, the last row cells can use only one line. I added the `cellspace` package, to have some vertical padding at the top and bottom of cells, and replaced `2$^{nd}$` (which is wrong anyway: it produces an italic nd, like two variables) with `2\textsuperscript{nd}`. Finally, I replaced your `C` column type (its widthcalculated width did not talke into account the value of `tabcolsep` and `arrayrulewidth`) with a `c` \multicolumn, and used `makecell` to have manual line breaks where needed. No `\adjustwidth` is necessary:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm, showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}S{m{#1}}}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X, C}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}\footnotesize
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{16}{S{X}|}} \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|Sc|}{ GQD} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{ BN-zigzag-ed-GQD} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{ BN-partial-ed-GQD} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|Sc|}{Avg. edge} & \multicolumn{2}{Sc|}{\makecell{Avg. 2\textsuperscript{nd} \\ zigzag line}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ B-border} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ N-border} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ B-edge} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ N-edge} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ B-border} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ N-border} \\
    \hline
    spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$ & spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$ & spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$ & spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$ & spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$ & spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$ & spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$ & spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$ \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!ht]
  \centering\setlength\tabcolsep{1.5pt}\scriptsize
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{16}{S{X}|}} \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|Sc|}{ GQD} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{ BN-zigzag-ed-GQD} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{ BN-partial-ed-GQD} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Avg. edge} & \multicolumn{2}{Sc|}{\makecell{Avg. 2\textsuperscript{nd}\\ zigzag line}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ B-border} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ N-border} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ B-edge} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ N-edge} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ B-border} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ N-border} \\ \hline
    spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$ & spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$ & spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$ & spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$ & spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$ & spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$ & spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$ & spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$ \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this answer also is not working :(

Comment: I finally understood why: the  `C` column type width wasl calculated not taking into accounts all the parameters (some explanations in my updated answer). It was simpler to use the `c` type, and use `\makecell`, which allows for line breaks inside cells.

Comment: Hi Bernard. Thanks for your effort. Its also working. But, I need to adopt many new things, which I am not interested to do at this moment. Erek answer suits me the best. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you looking for?

[image]

**Edit (2):**
After edition of your question I adopt my answer to new data which you provide. In this I change your preamble:

- move `hypperref` package to the end of preamble, where it should be (since it can change some settings in other packages)
- move `geometry` package on the place immediately after `documentclass`
- remove settings for text size ... because they are already determined by˛`geometry` package
- comment all package which I haven't installed in my laptop and which not influence on table formatting

  In design of your table I use your definition for column type `M`. I use iz in tabular preamble as well in `multicolumns` in the second row of table. Also I remove `resizebox`, to my taste its use in such cases should be avoided. Beter is determined smaller font-- in this case I use `\footnotesize` -- and reduce inter column space.

Code:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{report}
 \usepackage[top=1.0in, bottom=1.0in, left=1.0in, right=1.0in]{geometry}

 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{multicol}

 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{array,booktabs}
 \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
 \newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
 %\usepackage[dvips]{color}  % comment it to run with png images and pdflatex
 %\usepackage{epsfig} %Sharma commented
 \usepackage{graphicx} % Sharma introduced

 %\usepackage{mciteplus}
 %\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
 %\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}
 %\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

 \usepackage{enumerate}
 \usepackage{bm}
 \usepackage{braket}
 \usepackage{microtype}
 %\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
 \usepackage{color}

\usepackage[linktocpage,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}

%surplus settings ... this determine geometry package!
%\setlength{\textheight}{23cm}
%\setlength{\textwidth}{15cm}
%\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.4in}
%\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}

    \begin{document}
    \medskip
\begin{table}[h]
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
    \centering
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabular}{|*{16}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}M{0.8cm}|}}          \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{ GQD}
    &   \multicolumn{4}{c|}{BN-zigzag-ed-GQD}
        &   \multicolumn{8}{c|}{BN-partial-ed-GQD}                      \\  \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|M{1.6cm}|}{Avg. edge}
    &   \multicolumn{2}{M{1.6cm}|}{Avg. 2$^{nd}$ zigzag line}
        &   \multicolumn{2}{M{1.6cm}|}{ B-border}
            &   \multicolumn{2}{M{1.6cm}|}{ N-border}
                &   \multicolumn{2}{M{1.6cm}|}{B-edge}
                    &   \multicolumn{2}{M{1.6cm}|}{ N-edge}
                        &   \multicolumn{2}{M{1.6cm}|}{ B-border}
                            &   \multicolumn{2}{M{1.6cm}|}{ N-border}   \\  \hline
spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$  & spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$  & spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$  & spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$  & spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$  & spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$  & spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$  & spin-${\alpha}$ & spin-${\beta}$ \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

The above code is tested.

IN my answer I focused only to vertically and horizontally centering of cells content. If you like to improve table layout, please consider to use `makecell` package and its macro `\thead{...}` for settings heads of table columns and other possibilities  for enlarge gaps above and below cell contents (see package documentation).

Comment: Unedited answer is already what I have. I have tried with the edited answer as well. But, that's also not working. Have you tried?

Comment: @SharmaSRKChaitanyaYamijala, my MWE is tested, By it I generate provided picture of table. And now I tested again. It works for sure. In your code in question is error, one `mulltiline` isn't close with `}`. I test I use MikTeX, recent 64-bit version. If my code doesn't work, please tell me what is the error. In my answer, as you can see, I didn't bother with width of table. I can suggest you, how I will make it wider than text (without `resizebox`), if you wish (this was not your question).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your answer is also working. I prefered Krnk's answer as it require less changes to my document. Thank you for your time.